# Encrypt/decrypt javascript object into/from string - node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, encryption, hash

I'm searching for solution of encrypting my javascript object with some data (e.g. `{ data: [{...}, {...}] }` ) into string and then be able to decrypt this back to the same object. These operations will be done on node.js server.

For now I'm stringifying object with `JSON.stringify` and then using `base64` url encoding and decoding with https://www.npmjs.org/package/b64url. What I don't like here is that output string is even longer than stringified json.

I would like to have encrypted string with some restricted size. Is it possible? Maybe there are some npm packages ready for that purporse?

Thanks!

Comment: *encrypted string with some restricted size* - you cannot guarantee a size AND be able to decrypt it back, do you understand that? )

Comment: @raina77ow I'm not an expert in encryption algorithms, but understand that it cannot be smaller but just thought there are some algorithms that won't increase the string length

Comment: Check [rot](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/rot) then, or similar modules implementing rotation algorithms.

Comment: What kind of encryption are you looking for? The "major governments can't break it" flavor or the "kid next door can't look into my JSON data" pseudo cryptography? Rotational ciphers and base64 *encoding* are the latter kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote a NPM module that copes with this - **object-encrypter** https://github.com/voronianski/node-object-encrypter.

Comment: Hi and wow very helpful package! But there is one issue: how can someone use this in Angular 4? After installation:
`import * as ObjEncrypt from 'object-encrypter';`
and then
`var engine = ObjEncrypt(key);
console.log(engine.encrypt(user));`
but I get this error:
`index.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: crypto.createHmac is not a function
    at hmac (index.js:8)
    at Object.../../../../object-encrypter/index.js (...`
Thanks!